# Can rspec be used to feature test an integrated rails-angular app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, capybara

I have a very basic, integrated rails-angular app. It just renders a link, which uses data from a get request to rails:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularRspec.controllers')
  .controller('FightersController',
    function($scope, $http){
      console.log("FightersController is loaded...");
      $scope.fighters = [];
      $http.get('./fighters.json').
        success(function(data, status){
          $scope.fighters = data;
          console.log(status);
          console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(status);
          console.log(headers);
        });
  });
```

When I run a spec like this, and use pry, my link does not appear:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Index of Fighters' do

  let!(:fighter) { create(:fighter) }

  scenario 'User visits home', js: true do
    visit '/'
    binding.pry
    expect(true).to eq true
  end
end
```

But, I have confirmation from the console that angular is loading in the test browser, and the response is a 200. The issue doesn't appear to be browser specific. I've posted a repo here: [angular_rspec](https://github.com/robophilosopher/angular_rspec).

Here is my spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

end
```

And here is my rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Here is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularRspec">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "angular rspec" %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Angular Rspec</h1>
      <div ng-view></div>
      <div ng-controller="FightersController" id="primary"></div>
    </div>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your `create(:fighter)` call is running in a different thread (and database transaction) than the AJAX get request. Try adding this snippet to your `rails_helper`.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

Source: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the javascript driver for capybara:

```
Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
```

Comment: Thanks! I dropped that line right after  `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium` but it didn't seem to help.